# Trying to solve $\max \limits_{\mathbf{x}} \sum_{i=1}^K \log_2(1+\frac{x_i a_{ii} }{\sum_{n \ne i} x_n a_{ni} })$, s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^K x_i \le b$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem:
\begin{array}{rl} 
\max \limits_{\mathbf{x}} & \sum_{i=1}^K \log_2(1+\frac{x_i a_{ii} }{\sum_{n \ne i} x_n a_{ni} }) \\
\mbox{subject to} & \sum_{i=1}^K x_i \le b
\end{array}
Here, $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\ldots,x_K]$, and $a_{ni}$ (for all $i$ and $n$), $a_{ii}$ and $b$ are some positive constants. Note that the $x_i$ are non-negative.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this is convex?

Comment: @MichaelGrant you mean concave ? I tried to derive the second derivative but it is difficult to analyze.

Comment: You tagged this as a convex optimization problem. That would require that the optimization function be concave (since you are maximizing). I don't think it is, though I am not 100% certain. If you don't _know_ it is, though, then you have to treat it as an "ordinary" nonlinear optimization problem.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for editing the tags. Could you please tell me if the answer given below is correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have well understood your problem:

If you take $K=2$, your sum is $$S=\log_2(1+\frac{a_1x_1}{a_2x_2})+\log_2(1+\frac{a_2x_2}{a_1x_1})$$
Now if you suppose that $x_1=b-x_2$ with $b>x_2>0$, and you let $x_2\to 0$, it is clear that $S\to +\infty$. So in this case, the max does not exists. For $K\geq 3$, take $x_i=0$ for $i\geq 3$, and use the same procedure.

Comment: I am sorry, but before I formulated the problem in a wrong manner. Please consider my new modifications.

Comment: For $K=2$, you sum is now $$S=\log_2(1+\frac{a_{1,1}x_1}{a_{2,1}x_2})+\log_2(1+\frac{a_{2,2}x_2}{a_{1,2}x_1})$$, so I think that the problem is the same ?

Comment: I made the modifications just to highlight the facts that $a_{11}$ is not the same as $a_{12}$ and $a_{21}$ is not the same as $a_{22}$.

Comment: I have not been clear: with the new formulation, you can take $x_1=b-x_2$, $b>x_2>0$, and let $x_2\to 0$ to get that the sum is unbounded as before.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your answer provides the global max. Do you think that other optimal points (local max) exist ? If so, is it simple to find them ? Thank you!